# sequentially-consistent atomic load on x86

Tags: assembly, x86, atomic, memory-barriers, memory-model

I'm interested in sequentially-consistent load operation on x86.

As far as I see from assembler listing, generated by compiler it is implemented as a plain load on x86, however plain loads as far as I know guaranteed to have acquire semantics, while plain stores are guaranteed to have release.

Sequentially-consistent store is implemented as locked xchg, while load as plain load. That sounds strange to me, could you please explain this in details?

**added**

Just found in internet, that sequentially-consistent atomic load could be done as simple mov as long as store is done with locked xchg, but there was no proof and no links to documentation.

Answer (score 10):

A plain `MOV` on x86 is sufficient for an atomic sequentially consistent load, as long as SC stores are done with `LOCK`ed instructions, the value is correctly aligned, and "normal" WB cache mode is used.

See my blog post at http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/intel-memory-ordering-and-c++-memory-model.html for the full mapping, and the Intel processor docs at http://developer.intel.com/products/processor/manuals/index.htm for the details of the allowed orderings.

If you use "WC" cache mode or "non-temporal" instructions such as `MOVNTI` then all bets are off, as the processor doesn't necessarily write the data back to main memory in a timely manner.

Comment: See also [Why is integer assignment on a naturally aligned variable atomic on x86?](//stackoverflow.com/q/36624881) for the atomicity guarantees (which are separate from any ordering guarantees).

Comment: https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~pes20/cpp/cpp0xmappings.html does cover ordering.  You need a full barrier on either loads or stores to recover sequential consistency on top of x86's acq_rel model (actually seq-cst + a store-buffer with store forwarding), as the links in the question explain. Compilers chose to put the extra cost on stores so pure loads could be cheap.

Answer (score 2):

Reads on x86 are by nature atomic, so long as they are aligned, the section under the `MOV` instruction in the intel assembly manuals vol 2A should mention this, same with the `LOCK` prefix. Other volumes may also mention this

however, if you want an `atomic read`, you can use `_InterlockedExchangeAdd((LONG*)&var,0)` aka `LOCK XADD`, this will yield the old value, but won't change its value, the same can be done with `InterlockCompareExchange((LONG*)&var,var,var)` aka `LOCK CMPXCHG`, but IMO, there is no need for this

Comment: This is about getting seq-cst *ordering*, not just atomicity.  You only want to use an atomic RMW as a load if you also want a full memory barrier as part of the load.  And BTW, `CAS(&var, 0,0)` would never modify the value and avoid doing a non-atomic load of the shared variable first.

Answer (score 1):

Register to memory transfers and vice versa are not necessarily atomic in an multiprocessor environment.

**READING**

```
XOR EAX, EAX
LOCK XADD [address], EAX
```

This first instruction will zero the EAX register, the second instruction will exchange the content of both EAX with [address] and will store the sum of both in [address] again. Since EAX register was zero before, nothing gets changed.

**WRITING**

```
XCHG [address], EAX
```

EAX register will get the value to store to specified address.

**EDIT**: LOCK ADD EAX, [address] will cause an "Invalid Opcode Exception" because destination operand is no memory address.

> An invalidopcode exception (#UD) is generated when the LOCK prefix is used with any other
>   instruction or when no write operation is made to memory. [8.1.2.2 Software Controlled Bus Locking](http://www.intel.com/Assets/ja_JP/PDF/manual/253668.pdf)

**Edit 2**: Summarizes information from comments.

While

> "[...] the processor’s locking protocol is automatically implemented
>   for the duration of the exchange operation, regardless of the presence
>   or absence of the LOCK prefix or of the value of the IOPL."

There are restrictions to this

> "Accesses to cacheable memory that are split across bus widths, cache lines, and page boundaries are not guaranteed to be atomic"

Comment: They are, read "8.1.1 Guaranteed Atomic Operations" from Intel's manuals volume 3A. Still, your method is useful in cases where little is known about the address' alignment (the LOCK in your second code is unneeded as the processor will always LOCK with the XCHG instruction anyway)

Comment: Ok, you are right "If a memory operand is referenced, the processor’s locking protocol is automatically implemented for the duration of the exchange operation, regardless of the presence or absence of the LOCK prefix or of the value of the IOPL." but this document also sais "Accesses to cacheable memory that are split across bus widths, cache lines, and page boundaries are not guaranteed to be atomic"

Comment: @bkausbk Why would a regular variable be "split across bus widths, cache lines, and page boundaries"?

Comment: @curiousguy For example if page boundary is 4096 bytes and you are trying to access 4 bytes at the offset 4094, the first 2 bytes are stored in offset 4094...4095 and the last 2 bytes are stored in 4096..4097. In this case your "variable" would be splitted across page boundary.

Comment: @bkausbk OK but do you agree that wouldn't happen to a word size variable allocated accorded to usual conventions?

Comment: @curiousguy I don't know what "accorded to usual conventions" means. However you should keep in mind that you usually have no control on how your data is cached in background, if it is split across page boundary and so on. If you carefully design your application you can force certain things see "data prefetch" and "data structure alignment" for more information about that.

Comment: You're taking things out of context.  *"Accesses to cacheable memory that are split across bus widths, cache lines, and page boundaries are not guaranteed to be atomic"* only applies to load or store *without* a `lock` prefix, like `mov eax, [mem]` (which *is* guaranteed to be atomic for aligned mem, which is why compilers use `alignof( atomic<T> )  = sizeof(T)` for lock-free atomics.  See [Why is integer assignment on a naturally aligned variable atomic on x86?](//stackoverflow.com/q/36624881)

Comment: The only reason you *would* use a slow locked operation for both loads and stores is if your atomic variable was split across an 8-byte boundary.  **But the *much* better fix is to align your atomic vars so you can use cheap loads!!**  You only need a `lock`ed operation for atomic RMW, or for seq-cst ordering of either loads or stores.  You can choose one or the other; the normal choice is cheap loads.  See https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~pes20/cpp/cpp0xmappings.html

Comment: @bkausbk When is a word size variable split across pages? Which system allocates variables like that?

Comment: @curiousguy It is all about accessing a piece of memory in unaligned fashion. This can be done in so many ways.

Comment: @bkausbk: if your data is split across cache lines, fences can't help you; you *need* a `lock` prefix.  But the performance of split locks is catastrophic.  You might as well use a spinlock, i.e. fall back to the non `lock_free` mode of operation for misaligned `atomic<T>` if you insist on supporting `alignf(atomic<int>) = 1`.  Most systems don't; `alignof(atomic<T>) = sizeof(T)` and misaligned-object UB can result in tearing.  Also, your program won't be portable to non-x86 systems if it relies on misaligned atomics; most LL/SC machines don't have anything that allows misaligned atomics.