# Why can GCC elide memory barriers in a C11 atomic_load?

Tags: c, gcc

In this simple C11 program

```
#include <stdatomic.h>

int f(atomic_int* obj) {
  return atomic_load(obj);
}
```

I'd expect that the generated assembly would include a memory barrier. Even though the load itself might be atomic, the CPU might speculate (i.e. move) some read of this memory location in the caller of `f` across the call. However, `gcc -O` outputs:

```
        .file   "repro.c"
        .text
        .globl  f
        .type   f, @function
f:
.LFB0:
        .cfi_startproc
        movl    (%rdi), %eax
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
        .size   f, .-f
        .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 4.9.1"
        .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Why isn't a memory barrier needed here?

Comment: Possibly answered for x86 by this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4972106/sequentially-consistent-atomic-load-on-x86

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intel documentation says ["Reads are not reordered with other reads" (section 8.2.2)](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-3a-part-1-manual.pdf)

GCC generates the `mfence` instruction on `atomic_store` only. As far as I can wrap my head around it this should be enough to make sure that the write order seen by other CPUs is the same as on the CPU doing the store.